# Sophisticated checkbox form

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

How on earth do I make this work?

I have a database with 3 tables.

Table 1: Categories
Table 2: Organisations
Table 3: Link table with 2 colums: Category id, Organisation id.

I want to make this interface:

http://www.glowong.nl/Uploads/26-03-2012-13-46-52.jpg

When I click on 'Opslaan/save'. The new connections should be written to Table 3.

I don't know where to start.

Comment: And what exactly is your issue? The HTML part, processing the form in PHP or the SQL query to use?

Comment: I even tried to get the vertical text going but I find only that difficult enough. I'm using -transform's in css and they flip perfectly even for IE. But the rest just messes up.

Comment: I also can't figure out whether the OP is looking for HTML layout help or SQL help.  The question seems to be asking for help rendering HTML, but the tags and background are about SQL.  @GillianLo-Wong, can you please clarify?  What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: I´ve set up the html myself. But I´m thinking for a best way to run the whole update query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, I would do something like so:

1) When you render the page HTML, make each Organization a named array of checkboxes where the values are the categories, like so:

```
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="naam1[]" value="Hosting"> 
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="naam1[]" value="Crediteur">
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="naam1[]" value="Debiteur">
....
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="naam2[]" value="Hosting"> 
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="naam2[]" value="Crediteur">
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="naam2[]" value="Debiteur">
```

etc

2) When the form is submitted, loop through your org/categories like so:

```
foreach ($orgs as $org) {
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
         if (in_array($category,$_POST[$org])) {
             //the category for the given org was checked; 
             //make sure this relationship exists in the DB
         } else {
            //category for this org not checked;
            //if the relationship exists in the DB, delete it
         }
    }
}
```

I think something like that would work. You could have problems with this solution if you have a whloe bunch of orgs and categories since we're doing a Cartesian-ish join in the loops, but if you have that many orgs and categories you may need to rethink your interface anyhow.

Comment: Thanks Raj, your named array idea got me on my way!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this relates to your user interface, but what you seem to be asking for is an `INSERT INTO` command that gets its data from a `SELECT`.  For example:

```
INSERT INTO table3 ( category, organization )
  SELECT categ.name,org.name FROM categ, org
    WHERE categ.id=org.categ;
```

But if you're trying to make this part of a user interface, then perhaps you don't really want this to be a third *table* as much as an array in PHP which you'll use to populate the HTML form.  I don't think I know enough about how your data are stored to be able to comment on that in a useful way.